# How do I add breakpoints to a stored SQL Procedure for debugging?

Tags: sql, debugging, sql-server-2008, breakpoints

I am trying to debug a SQL procedure, and am using the following query to do so.

```
USE [database]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Populate]
        @ssId = 201

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

The problem is, the procedure I am testing, (Populate) doesn't seem to stop at any of the breakpoints I assign to it. Is there a different way to add breakpoints such that I can follow the debugger? I am getting the following error: "Invalid line number specified with SQL breakpoint".

Comment: SQL doesn't have breakpoints - AFAIK, this is a Visual Studio thing - see this article for setting breakpoints: http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051607-1.aspx

Comment: @OMG Ponies For SQL Server 2005, you use Visual Studio. But for 2008, you can easily debug in Management Studio.

Comment: @DOK: Cool!  I'm stuck in 2005 land :(  I wonder if SSMS Express has debugging, and if it'll backport to 2005...

Comment: @OMG Ponies Yeah, I'm mostly in 2005, too. But I remembered this as one of the benefits of moving to 2008. You could help lots of folks by checking out that SQL 2008 Express work-around and letting us know.

Comment: @DOK: Well, I know the intellisense doesn't backport from 2008 to 2005 - I wouldn't want to get anyone's hopes up.  But I'll make a note to look at it if I remember.

Comment: @OMG Ponies Darn, I found this near the end of one of the articles I cited -- http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1695 : "Limitation: If you are connecting to SQL Server 2005 even from SQL Server 2008 SSMS, you would not be able to debug your routines"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, **if you have SQL Server 2008, you can once again debug in Management Studio**.

Each of these articles will take you through it step by step, with screenshots. It could hardly be easier.

[SQL Server 2008: The Debugger is back](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/07/31/sql-server-2008-the-debugger-is-back/)

[T-SQL Debugger is back in SQL Server 2008 ... debugging now made easy](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1695)

[New Features in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/New_Features_in%20_SSMSPart3_p1.aspx)

Comment: "This feature works with SSMS version 17.9.1 and earlier. [run-the-transact-sql-debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/run-the-transact-sql-debugger?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 4):

Follow these tutorials:

[Debugging Stored Procedures in SQL Server 2005](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article27.aspx)

[Debugging SQL Server CLR functions, triggers and stored procedures](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1624)

Answer (score 0):

1 Make a connection to a database.
2 Right-click the stored procedure, user-defined function, or trigger you want to work with and choose Open from the shortcut menu.

**To insert a break point**

1.Right-click the line of SQL syntax in the editor window where you want to insert a breakpoints.
2.Point to Break point and then click Insert Break point.